# ¿Cómo publicar correctamente un Web Service?

Tags: visual-studio, webservice, iis, wcf, web.config

Tengo una Web Service que ya desarrollé. Lo he probado con el Cliente WCF que incluye Visual Studio y todo perfecto en mi área local. Sin embargo, al momento de publicarlo en el servidor no logro probarlo de ninguna manera.

Soy novato creando Web Services, por lo que no sé si el error es mío al momento de publicarlo (algún permiso que me falte en IIS) o en alguna configuración que se me pasó añadir en mi Web.config.

-

Al momento de subir los archivos publicados al servidor, yo lo convierto a aplicación con IIS. Después, lo que hago es examinar dicha aplicación, al hacerlo me abre el navegador y me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: Archivos que aparecen en Chrome después de abrir la aplicación]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es acceder a mi Web Service (WSPedidos.svc) para poder invocarlo desde mi máquina, siendo que éste ya se encuentra publicado en el servidor. Sin embargo, al dar clic sobre él me aparece que no es accesible. Aparece el siguiente error:

> **Error HTTP 404.3 - Not Found**
>       No puede obtener acceso a la página solicitada debido a la configuración de la extensión. Si la página es un script, agregue un
>   controlador. Si se debe cargar el archivo, agregue una asignación
>   MIME.

Esta es mi sección *services* de mi Web.config:

```
<services>
              <service  name="WS_TVISAB2B.WSPedidos"
                  behaviorConfiguration="RealizarProductos">

                <endpoint address=""
                    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_IWSPedidos"
                    contract="WS_TVISAB2B.IWSPedidos" name="MetadataExchangeHttpBinding_IWSPedidos" />           
              </service>
</services>
```

No sé si se deba a alguna mala configuración mía en el IIS al momento de publicar el Web Service, o algo que me faltó añadir en el propio Web Service.
¿Podrían orientarme un poco? He buscado por dos días pero no encuentro solución alguna.

-

Ya logré exponer los metadatos, sí me hizo falta una configuración en el web.config.
Debía colocar el siguiente endpoint:

```
<endpoint
    address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    contract="IMetadataExchange"
/>
```

Pero ahora me surgió otro problema. 
Ya puedo encontrar mi WS publicado en el servidor desde el Cliente del WCF con el que cuenta Visual Studio. Sin embargo, al momento de mandarle el parámetro que requiere para ser ejecutado me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> "No había ningún extremo escuchando en
>   http://websrv/WSPedidos/WSPedidos.svc que pudiera aceptar el mensaje.
>   La causa suele ser una dirección o una acción SOAP incorrecta.
>   Consulte InnerException, si está presente, para obtener más
>   información".

Y la información que tiene mi InnerException es la siguiente:

> Inner Exception: No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: 'websrv'    en
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()

Estuve leyendo en internet y aparentemente es algo del proxy.
Probé lo que proponían como solución en distintas páginas, pero realmente no me funcionó a mí.
¿Alguien ha pasado por el mismo inconveniente? ¿Y cómo logró solucionarlo?
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: yo generalmente al publicar los web services en el iis no muevo tanto el web config, es algo preecho, seria bueno poder ver la interface y la clase para ver el alcance de la funcion, se que el codigo esta bien, pero quisiera saber como estas seteando el servicio en el .cs

Comment: Hola, veo que la pregunta tiene mucho tiempo, pero lo que debes hacer es exponer primero el endpoint en httpBinding, para ver que todo funcione bien. Luego haciendo comentario sobre la respuesta que te dieron, esta mal la respuesta porque cuando le haces clic al servicio debe mostrarte que esta funcionando, no tiene nada que ver el pasarle el parametro del metodo que necesitas consultar, porque eso lo haces mas que nada cuando quieres hacer la consulta con el servicio configurado para REST, y entonces de devuelve el json o xml en el explorador.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando accedes a un servicio digamos que lo publicas con el nombre ***WSPedidos.svc*** pero la funcion de adentro ( a cual pretendes que se ejecute es obtenerPedidos) para ejecutarlo deberias llamarlo:

```
http:// mi.dominio.com/WSPedidos.svc/obtenerPedidos
```

Recuerda que en el ***cs*** debe ir declarado que es un ***WebInvoke*** y que es un `POST`, o un `GET` para poderlo invocar. Me comentas, ***IIS*** tiene sus mañas. tambien para saber si el servicio esta funcionando bien puedes darle click derecho **>** establecer como pagina principal **>** lo ejecutas, y te debe salir una descripcion del servicio, (top de la web azul y unos recuadros que describen el interior del servicio) sale una pantalla asi es que todo va bien.

Comment: Vaya, no sabía que había que incluir la función que quiero ejecutar en la URL.
Logré publicar el WS con éxito, al abrirlo en el servidor ya me arroja la pantalla con el top azul como mencionas, y en la primera línea dice "Creó un servicio".
Sin embargo, ahora tengo duda sobre cómo invocar el WS desde mi máquina.
A lo que entiendo, debo hacerlo desde la dirección (http://mi.dominio.com/WSPedidos/WSPedidos.svc/RealizarPedido). 
Pero me es imposible acceder a él. Me sale un error de que no tiene acceso a los metadatos, que debo exponerlos. Según yo ya los expuse, pero el error persiste. :(

Comment: puedes mostrar la interface?

Comment: Ya logré solucionar el problema que te había mencionado en mi comentario anterior. Pero me surgió otro, lo añadí como Edición a mi pregunta. Muchas gracias por la orientación.

Comment: La respuesta esta en parte mal, porque tu caso es para que el servicio sea transformado a REST, y el servicio por defecto esta en SOAP y al hacerle click debe funcionar y mostrarte que esta en funcionamiento. El problema se debe a una configuración del IIS.